# how to read the attachments stored using multer - nodejs/expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, attachment, multer

I am new to node programming, I am trying to build an app which will be having a feature where users will be uploading there docs/images and then afterwards they can also view the same files which they had uploaded earlier.

I came across multer with which I built an API which stores the attached file on the server, please refer below code :

```
app.post('/submit-form', uploadPlugin.single('files'),(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    if (!req.file){
            res.status(400).json({"error":"Something went wrong while uploading file"})
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            path  = "C:\\Users\\APIs" + req.file.path
            console.log(path)
            res.sendFile(path);
        }   

})
```

Now my problem is if at all I need to view the attached files, how can I do so (For ex: if someone uploads an Image it should show this image was uploaded)

I am trying to send the file as the response but in the HTML page it just shows gibberish (probably the byte stream, refer the image attached) instead it should display the actual document say image for example.

[image]

Comment: Check the Content-Type header in your response

Comment: I tried by setting content-type image/jpeg, but it didn't work same gibberish